# Software Where Users Can fill in forms on Wordpress site and responses display in content via shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I have been looking all over for a specific type of software that would allow a user that is on the front end of a Wordpress website to fill out a short form and then after submission, the response that the user filled in would show in the content via short code.

For example, when the user could enter their name in a single-box form. Then, in the content, Wordpress would display their name where ever the shortcode [user_name] is entered.

I might have a piece of content, a blog post for example, where if the user's name was Bill, and they filled out the form with their name, then in the content, it would say "Hi, Bill!" because in the post, I've put "Hi [user_name]!"

Does anyone know of software or plugin that does this?